# Is this $\|Ax\|\leq \lambda_{max}\|x\|$ correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

Assume $\lambda_{max}$ is the eigenvalue with largest modulus. But we don't assume $A$ has $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors. So if this correct, please gives me a proof. If not, please gives me a counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. Then $\lambda_\max = 0$,
but $A e_2 = e_1$, hence $\|Ae_2\| > 0 = \lambda_\max \|e_1\|$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But could you further give me a example when $\lambda_{max}>0$?

Comment: @User1006: What is true only if $A$ is symmetric? The $A$ above is not symmetric and all the calculations are pretty straightforward.

Comment: @Gatsby: Add $\epsilon$ to the diagonal of $A$ and continuity shows the above holds for sufficiently small $\epsilon$. In this case $\lambda_\max = \epsilon$, of course.

Answer (score 2):

This holds if $A$ is Hermitian.

Let $A$ be Hermitian, i.e. $\:\overline{A}^{T}=A$. By Spectral Theorem, $A$ is unitarily similar to a diagonal matrix, i.e
$$
\overline{Q}^{T}AQ=\pmatrix{\mu_1 \\ & \ddots \\ && \mu_n}=D
$$
where $\space \overline{Q}^{T}Q=I$, $\mu_i$ is eigenvalues of $A$. So
$$
\overline{Q}^{T}\overline{A}^{T}Q=\pmatrix{\overline{\mu_1} \\ & \ddots \\ && \overline{\mu_n}}=\overline{D}
$$
And 
\begin{align}
\|Ax\|^2&=\overline{(Ax)}^T(Ax)
\\
&=\overline{x}^{T}\overline{A}^{T}Ax
\\
&=\overline{x}^{T}Q\bar{D}\overline{Q}^{T}Q {D}\overline{Q}^{T}x
\\
&=\overline{y}^{T}{D^2}y&&{(y=\overline{Q}^{T}x)}
\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n|\lambda_i|^2|y_i|^2
\\
&\leqslant |\lambda_{max}|^2\sum_{i=1}^n|y_i|^2
\\
&=|\lambda_{max}|^2\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^2
\\
&=|\lambda_{max}|^2\|x\|^2
\end{align}
Hence we have
$$
\|Ax\|\leqslant |\lambda_{max}|\|x\|
$$